# what is the purpose of Appium Client Library JAR alone?

Tags: java, appium

I saw that there is need to download server for using Appium + [Appium Client Library](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:io.appium%20AND%20a:java-client) when i'm using JAVA , there is small arrow over there to download the JAR only , beside there is option to use the POM.xml and there is dependencies over there so that maven will download them, so what is the purpose of the stand alone JAR if there is need (according to the POM) for more jars?

Comment: The POM is used if your are using a Maven framework.  While I use Maven in all my projects, there are other frameworks, and you can also just simply download and add the jar file to your classpath manually.  Sometimes when there's a firewall, POM doesn't always work, so downloading and installing a .jar is a way to work around that.

Comment: Thanks but i know these, the question is why the POM there have a lot more dependencies that will be downloaded eventualy and will be like the JAR i was mention, and if i download the JAR alone, it should work? i mean, why in the POM there is many files while in other hand there is only one JAR client? if there is need to rest of the files so why they didn't add the rest of the needed jars and if not, why the POM have them?